# Creating a message box in C# with custom buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

Would like to know if it is possible to create a MessageBox with custom buttons similar to what one would achieve with showOptionDialog in java?

```
String[]colors = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
int color = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please choose color", "Color please", 0, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null, colors, colors[0]);
if(color == 0)
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red it is");
}
```

What would the equivalent for this be in C#?

Comment: Don't know the java showOptionDialog, but perhaps this will help: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17026/TaskDialog-for-WinForms) - There are other similar ones on CodeProject too, but I  note your 'WinForms' tag...

Comment: Title says C#. Question asks about Java? Which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that the answer is: you can't.

There is no way to alter the MessageBox as far as I know. You will need to code your own dialog (is not that hard).

Probably the MessageBox class is making a WinApi call at the end and that could be the main reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

http://snipplr.com/view/14245/custom-messagebox-buttons/

Here is similar approach, in C++, but with more explanation:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10037/How-to-change-the-MessageBox-window-Add-controls-a

**NOTE:** Just be aware that the WinApi messagebox is optimized to be able to display even under very low memory conditions. So the OS can display messages in a crash or low memory condition.

If you mess with it, like above, you may lose some of that robustness.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. The messagebox class has only private constructor so you can't derive from it. However, as SoMoS already wrote, you could make your own custom message box by using a windows form and its showdialog() method. Hope it helped

Comment: What's the point in writing an answer that just says, "that other answer was correct"?  Just upvote the other answer if you feel it is correct.

Comment: Answers exist to answer questions, not as a place to just put anything.  If you have interesting tidbits of information that you would like to share that relate to a question/answer, that don't make up a full-fledged answer, then you should post them as a comment.  That would be the appropriate response in this case.

Comment: True, he can upvote but there is a difference in both answers, _firefly_ mentioned that OP can use _windows form_ and _ShowDialog()_ to get such a message box.